# How do you delete a remote git branch "properly", a.k.a. updating the remote branch list for all users?

Tags: git, branch

I'm trying to delete a remote git branch, however the process isn't "fully" deleting the branch as I'd expect.

Let's say for example I'm deleting a branch called `mybranch`. To do this, I run the following command,

```
git push origin :mybranch
```

This removes the branch as expected, and if I do `git branch -a` it no longer appears on the list locally or remotely.

The problem I'm having is if I go another person's machine who did a `git pull` while the branch existed, and they perform a `git branch -a`, it's still in their list as a remote branch.

We've tried multiple commands, `pull`, `gc`, `prune`, but nothing is updating this list and removing the remote branch.

**Is there a command to sync (what I can only assume is) the local cache of the remote branches list, and remove any remote branches that no longer exist?**

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Until they update their remotes, their git will have no knowledge of what's happened on the repository.  Once they've done an update (via `git fetch` or `git remote update`), `git remote show origin` will correctly show that they have local tracking branches for branches that no longer exist upstream.  At that point, `git remote prune` can be used to remove the stale local branches.

Answer (score 23):

To remove any remote-tracking branches which no longer exist on the remote.

```
git fetch -p
```